# create references in each section in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, reproducible-research

I want to use Rmarkdown but what I've read is that when creating a bibliography using pandoc, references go at the end of the document:

[pandoc/citeproc issues: multiple bibliographies, nocite, citeonly](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pandoc-discuss/bibliography$20in$20each$20section%7Csort:relevance/pandoc-discuss/6Qd9tBVdw-s/BuyZSU25qDwJ)

So even if I have a parent document named thesis.Rmd, I assume that all references would go at the end of that file.

I need that each thesis' chapter or section must have its own references,  is there any other way  to solve this than putting a bibliography header in each chapter I write and then knit each chapter separetely?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this. I had a simpler problem (moving the biblio section before the appendix section) and had to write a quick pandoc filter just for that.

Comment: @SergioCorreia apparently I'm going to need and appendix after my  biblio section, could you please explain what is a pandoc filter for this and how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using [multiple-bibliographies.lua](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/multiple-bibliographies/multiple-bibliographies.lua) filter. However, .bib files should be chapter-specific.

Note: after pandoc >= 2.11 each chapter accepts only one .bib file as in this example

```
---
title: "Doc title"
author: "name name"
date: "23 08 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 1
    number_sections: true
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua

bibliography_chapter1: [chapter1.bib]
bibliography_chapter2: [chapter2.bib]
bibliography_chapter3: [chapter3.bib]    
csl: format.csl
link-citations: yes
---
```

At the end of each chapter add:

```
## References {-}

::: {#refs_chapterX}
:::
```